# Is there any simple method to include file in "form" in REACT and send it back to Express NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, multer

So, I have tried using the "append" form-data method to individual add key/pair values in the form and send back to the Express server, which is working fine. My question is, Is that possible to send file back to the express server just like any other fields that are passed to express. For example, when I don't include a file in the form, I can simply pass the "state" to the body of the request message, but when including a file, I have to append each state using the form-data append method. I am using the state(class component) to store the file. Below is the Code:

By the way, I am using multer to parse file.

**Form**

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleInputUser} encType="multipart/form-data">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="name">Name</Label>
                                <Input required id="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="desig">Designation</Label>
                                <Input required id="desig" value={this.state.desig} onChange={this.handleInputChange} name="desig" placeholder="Enter Designation" />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="image">Image(png/jpeg/jpg)</Label>
                                <Input required id="image" name="userImage" onChange={this.handleFile} type="file" />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Button size="lg" type="submit" color="primary">Post</Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
```

**Here is class component**

```
class Home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        msg: "empty",
        modal: false,
        name: "",
        desig: "",
        image: null
    };
    this.getMsg = this.getMsg.bind(this);
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    this.handleInputUser = this.handleInputUser.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
};

getMsg() {
    fetch(baseUrl + 'msg')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => this.setState({ msg: res.msg }));
    console.log("Clicked");
}

toggleModal() {
    this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
    });
}

handleInputUser(event) {
    console.log(this.state)
    var data = new FormData(); // form data
    data.append('name', this.state.name);
    data.append('desig', this.state.desig);
    data.append('userImage', this.state.image);

    fetch(baseUrl + 'users', {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => console.log("Submitted: ", res));

    this.toggleModal();
};

handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};

handleFile(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.files[0];
    this.setState({
        image: value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to make the inputs self-controlled, i.e. to not control their values via React states, and then pass the form into the FormData constructor.

```js
<Form onSubmit={this.handleInputUser} encType="multipart/form-data">
      <FormGroup>
           <Label for="name">Name</Label>
           <Input required id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
           <Label for="desig">Designation</Label>
           <Input required id="desig" name="desig" placeholder="Enter Designation" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
           <Label for="image">Image(png/jpeg/jpg)</Label>
           <Input required id="image" name="userImage" type="file" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
           <Button size="lg" type="submit" color="primary">Post</Button>
      </FormGroup>
</Form>

handleInputUser(event) {
    console.log(this.state)
    var form = event.currentTarget;
    var data = new FormData(form); //pass the form to FormData

    fetch(baseUrl + 'users', {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => console.log("Submitted: ", res));

    this.toggleModal();
};
```